# How to change default login URL in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i use module in my project

```
App -> 
   Modules ->
      Admin -> 
          Http ->
              controller
              middleware
              request
```

how i use authenticate and redirect auth file in this middleware 
authenticate file or redirectauth file in this middleware

authenticate.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                // return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
                return redirect()->guest('admin');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

redirectauthenticate.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            // return redirect('/home');
            return redirect('admin/dashbord');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

how i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain what is happening with your code, what problem are you having and what is expected?

Comment: after login i move to admin/dashbord when i logout and pass this path to URL then i move on auth/login.  i want i move on /admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appear in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating):

> When a user is not successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the `/auth/login` URI. You can customize the failed post-authentication redirect location by defining a `loginPath` property on the `AuthController`:

```
protected $loginPath = '/login';
```

In your case you will use `'/admin'` instead of `'/login'`.

Comment: how i use this in module ?

Comment: protected $loginPath = '/admin';
protected $redirectPath = 'admin/dashboard';       i use this. this is working but when i logout or i pass admin/dashboard in url they redirect in auth/login

Comment: Where is `AuthController`? I use Laravel 5.4.